# How to calculate exactly start psition of a ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I have a HorizontalScrollView display a list level (each level is a button). See the image below

[image]

I search and know that I can use the method

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y);
```

to set starting position but I really do not know how to calculate exactly the start position .
Example my current game level is 4, I want to set HorizontalScrollview starting position at Item 4, how can I calculate the exactly parameter which I need to fill on method scrollTo(x, y) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the photo, it seems that all your items have a fixed width and a fixed margin on the right.

To scroll to i-th position use:

```
x = i*(buttonWidth+marginRight);
ScrollView.scrollTo(x, buttonY); //Don't change the y value.
```

Where i starts from 0. So level 1 is i=0 and so on.